# Reading file from .csv in c++

Tags: c++, function, read.csv

I am writing a program that takes input from the .csv file. The program run but the problem is it only returns the last line of the .csv file and skips all the other 9 lines.
It also does not display the average and the grade. Please help me figure out what I am doing wrong.

The professor is very specific about using what we have learned so far and that is loops and functions. I can only use loops and functions so I am not allowed to use arrays.

Here's the scores.csv file

[image]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
int testScore1, testScore2, testScore3, testScore4, testScore5;
double avg;
char grade;

double getAvg(int testScore1, int testScore2, int testScore3, int testScore4, int testScore5){
    avg = (testScore1 + testScore2 + testScore3 + testScore4 + testScore5)/5;
    return avg;
}
char getGrade(double avg){
    if (avg >= 90){
        grade = 'A';
        cout << 'A' << endl;
    }else if (avg >= 80){
        grade = 'B';
        cout << 'B' << endl;
    }else if (avg >= 70){
        grade = 'C';
        cout << 'C' << endl;
    }else if (avg >= 60){
        grade = 'D';
        cout << 'D' << endl;
    }else{
        grade = 'F';
        cout << 'F' << endl;
    }
    return grade;
}

int main(){
    
    ifstream myFile;
    myFile.open("scores.csv");
    
    
    if(!myFile.is_open()){
        cout << "Error" << endl;
    }
    string testScore1, testScore2, testScore3, testScore4, testScore5;
    while (myFile.good()) {
        
        getline(myFile, testScore1, ',');
        getline(myFile, testScore2, ',');
        getline(myFile, testScore3, ',');
        getline(myFile, testScore4, ',');
        getline(myFile, testScore5, '\n');

    }
    
        cout<< setw(15) <<" Test scores"<<endl;
        cout<<"--------------------"<<endl;
        cout<< " 1   2   3   4   5   Avg  Grade"<<endl;
        cout<<"=== === === === === ===== ====="<<endl;
        cout<< " "<< testScore1<< "  "<< testScore2 << "  "<< testScore3 << "  "<< testScore4 << "  "<< testScore5<< "  " << getAvg << "  " << getGrade <<endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Amazing you got that far. I don't see any OCR code or even a call to a png reader.

Comment: @user4581301 I think the image is merely a graphical representation/example of the CSV file. The CSV file would actually contain `77,73,65,55,73` etc. directly, so no need for barcodes or anything.

Comment: You are not converting strings to integers either. (Example of full program: https://onlinegdb.com/uyPXXMy2z)

Comment: @AnthonyD973 thats correct.

Comment: @PKramer that would have made my work way easier, but the problem is I'm limited to using functions and loops only. I am not allowed to use arrays whatsoever.

Comment: @Welt That's strange, its like tying your hands to your back. I'd like to talk to your teacher :)

Comment: That's true. I am tied to what I can do. Just loops and functions because that's as far as we have covered in class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An answer has been given already and accepted.

To be complete, I will show a refactored and working version your code.

I uses no arrays. Just loops and functions.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

double getAvg(int testScore1, int testScore2, int testScore3, int testScore4, int testScore5){
    double avg = (testScore1 + testScore2 + testScore3 + testScore4 + testScore5)/5.0;
    return avg;
}
char getGrade(double avg){
    char grade = 'F';
    if (avg >= 90){
        grade = 'A';
    }else if (avg >= 80){
        grade = 'B';
    }else if (avg >= 70){
        grade = 'C';
    }else if (avg >= 60){
        grade = 'D';
    }
    return grade;
}

int main(){
    
    std::ifstream myFile("scores.csv");

    if(!myFile){
        std::cerr << "\nError: Could not open input file\n";
    }
    else {

        std::cout<< std::setw(15) <<" Test scores\n--------------------\n 1   2   3   4   5   Avg  Grade\n=== === === === === ===== =====\n";
       
        int testScore1, testScore2, testScore3, testScore4, testScore5;
        char comma1, comma2, comma3, comma4;
        
        // Read all values in one line, then next line, next line and so on
        while (myFile >> testScore1 >> comma1 >> testScore2 >> comma2 >> testScore3 >> comma3 >> testScore4 >> comma4 >> testScore5) {
            
            // Calculate
            double average = getAvg(testScore1, testScore2, testScore3, testScore4, testScore5);
            char grade = getGrade(average);
            std::cout<< " "<< testScore1<< "  "<< testScore2 << "  "<< testScore3 << "  "<< testScore4 << "  "<< testScore5<< "  " << average << "  " << grade << '\n';
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That simple tweak worked wonders. I appreciate you

Answer (score 2):

You print the values outside of the while loop, meaning you never save the previous values. Your program is essentially saying:
"Set t1 to test score row 0, col 0, set t2 to row 1, col 0, etc..."
The loop restarts, and now it goes:
"Set t1 to test score row 0, col 1, set t2 to row 1, col 1, etc..."
Do you see the problem? You overwrite the variables each time the loop runs, without saving them. The program then only prints the final line, because that's what the variables are when the loop ends.

You probably want to solve this by using a 2D array. Then, you can use a nested loop to set each spot to the corresponding value. Is that enough information to figure out the rest? If not let me know.

general idea:

new int[amount of rows][amount of cols] array; 
for(int i = 0; i = amount of rows; i++) 
for(int j=0; j=amount of cols; j++) 
array[i][j] = getline code here 
close loops.

Comment: Thanks. I have figured out the loop one. However, I am only allowed to use functions to solve for the average and the grade.

Comment: Sure, no extra functions are needed. You're just doing something like:
new int[amount of rows][amount of cols] array;
for(int i = 0; i = amount of rows; i++)
  for(int j=0; j=amount of cols; j++)
    array[i][j] = getline code here
close loops.

Sorry, I haven't written C++ in a while so it's pseudocode instead of the real syntax, but you should get the idea. Agh, and comments don't allow whitespace, so this looks garbage. let me edit my original post.

Comment: I do get the idea. The problem is I'm not allowed to use any arrays because that topic is further ahead.

Comment: I see. I'd edit your main post putting the restrictions of your assignment. Are you allowed to use pointer arrays (for example, int**)?

Comment: No. As far as I know, we have covered the basics, loops, and functions. Arrays are the next topic we cover.

Comment: Okay, so that is in fact a massive pain. I am guessing what your teacher wants you to do is create a nested loop. In the inner loop, you find the average of whatever row you're on. On the outer loop, you add that number to an overall counter. At the end of the loops, you divide that number by how many rows there are...unless he wants you to find the average of each row, and not the entire table...

Comment: Yes. He wants the average of each line and prints out a grade from a function. So I am not sure if i wrote the functions correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237568/discussion-between-gummysaur-and-welt).